# Java LWJGL Rendering pistol model at right side of screen

Tags: java, rotation, lwjgl

Hi everyone I'm working on weapon rendering and I got stuck in part when I have to calculate gun.y and gun.rot.x. Rotation on y axis and calculating x,z of gun works good. But now is question how I can get gun.rot.x and gun.y. My calculation of gun x and y looks like:

```
        float offsetX = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(camera.getRotation().y + 25));
        float offsetZ = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(camera.getRotation().y + 25)); 

        gun.x = camera.x + offsetX;
        gun.z = camera.z - offsetZ;
```

Y rotation of gun is really simple:

```
        gun.getRotation().y = 360 - camera.getRotation().y;
```

I tried to calculate gun.y with code like this:

```
float offsetY = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(camera.getTransform().getRotation().x + 25));
gun.y = camera.y - offsetY
```

But it seems to not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is rendering a viewmodel (the gaming term). this i generally done by having another camera parented by the player's camera. In other words, you would use a separate camera to render the model so that it looks close to the face (and also to avoid the gun going through walls for example) and then depending on your implementation add your viemodel camera's transformation to the main camera's transformation.

If you are using the fixed function pipeline (`glMatrixMode()`, `glTranslatef()` and so on) all you have to do is apply the transformation (call `glTranslatef()` and `glRotatef()`) without reseting the identity matrix (`glLoadIdentity()`). For example:

```
{ /* your rendering code */

    glLoadIdentity();
    camera.applyTransformation();

    render_scene();

    glPushMatrix(); // ensures that the transformation isent 
                    // directly applied to the matrix should
                    // you want to render more thing with the
                    // main camera after the view model
    viewmodelCamera.applyTransformation();

    render_viewmodel();

    glPopMatrix(); // complementary call for glPushMatrix()
                   // marks the end of this matrix operation
                   // on the matrix stack

    possibly_render_more_things() // if you wish

} /* end of rendering code */
```

If you are using matrices for your camera (which you should if you intend to properly use modern OpenGL), all you have to do is add the two MVP (Model View Projection) matrices, your base camera's and your modelview camra's, and pass the result of these to your shader for the gun rendering.

Hope this helped!

EDIT: Just thought I'd mention, the second camera is basically like working in model space for your gun model, you would use the units that you are currently storing in gun.x (for ex) (also don't use public variables), and make those the camera's transformation.